# Complex WP_Query order request: DESC by day, but then ASC by time

Tags: wp-query, order, date

I've got a site with a couple thousand time-stamped posts in a custom post type. These get displayed by a few taxonomies and a date query in various views (I've got that all working just fine already). The tricky part is ordering them by a unique date format: the client insists that posts should be ordered DESC by day, then ASC by time within each day. As far as I can see [in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters), `order` only takes `date` as a param, not day & time as distinguishable values. Is there any way to accomplish what I'm looking for without substantial re-writes of a half-dozen archive-tax template files?

I'm using the following to sort DESC by date already and would love a solution that fits into this function:

```
function my_post_sort( $vars ) {
    if ( is_tax(array('series', 'speakers', 'topics', 'venues'))) {
        $vars['order'] = 'ASC';
    }
    return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'my_post_sort');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using `query_vars` quite right - this filter is for whitelisting "public" query vars, not actually setting their values. It's also called rather early (`wp::parse_request`), so any conditional tags like `is_tax()` will always be false at this stage.

Use the `pre_get_posts` action for overriding the default query. Having said that, you need a custom `ORDER BY` clause. Use the `posts_orderby` filter:

```
function wpse_179686_posts_orderby( $orderby, $wp_query ) {
    if ( $wp_query->is_main_query() && $wp_query->is_tax( array( 'series', 'speakers', 'topics', 'venues' ) ) )
        $orderby = 'DATE( post_date ) DESC, TIME( post_date ) ASC';

    return $orderby;
}

add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'wpse_179686_posts_orderby', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I needed: didn't know about the `DATE()` and `TIME()` functions. And thanks for the reminder about which filter to use: not quite sure how I ended up with `query_vars`, but `posts_orderby` was what I meant.

Comment: Note that `posts_orderby` is for directly altering the SQL query. If you just need to change the default sorting, stick to `pre_get_posts` and `$wp_query->set( 'orderby', 'title_or_whatever' );` Happy coding!